# Gauss package: gmatrix not equivalent to corresponding amsmath environment

Tags: spacing, amsmath, matrices

The following quote is taken from the `gauss` package documentation:

> The package defines a new matrix environment `gmatrix` which behaves
>   just like Latex's and AMS-Latex's matrix.

But when using the `gmatrix` environment within `align`, the output is **not** equivalent to the corresponding `amsmath` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{gmatrix}[p]
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{gmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The parentheses are of equal height, but the line spacing is different, and in my opinion the upper version looks better:

[image: pmatrix vs. gmatrix]

Furthermore, the horizontal alignment of the whole matrix is a little bit different, but this might be due to some extra space needed when typesetting the matrix operations (which is the whole point of the `gauss` package).

Interestingly, when using `equation` instead of `align`, the first problem vanishes. Is there any way to get the same behaviour for the `align` environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `gauss` package directly uses `\halign` for building the matrix. This uses the current baselineskip, which, in `align` is enlarged.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\g@matrix
 {\vbox\bgroup}
 {\vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines}% restore the standard baselineskip
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{gmatrix}[p]
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{gmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{gmatrix}[p]
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{gmatrix}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

[image]