# How to typeset row operations on augmented matrix

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to typeset row operations on a augmented matrix, but the "gauss"-package does not seem to support the vertical line just before the
last column, any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package can't support typing `|` somewhere like in arrays. But we can emulate it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

% patch gauss macros for doing their work in `align'
% and other amsmath environments; see
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146532/
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\g@matrix
 {\vbox\bgroup}
 {\vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines}% restore the standard baselineskip
 {}{}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\BAR}{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \strut\vrule % the `\vrule` is as high and deep as a strut
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & \BAR & 3 \\
4 & 5 & \BAR & 6 \\
7 & 8 & \BAR & 9
\rowops
 \swap{0}{1}
 \mult{0}{\cdot 7}
 \add[5]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

In other words, I create a new column that takes no horizontal space, where I place a bar.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but there are gaps in the vertical line between the rows, sadly.

Comment: @mhle This might depend on the material in the rows; without an example it's difficult to say.

Comment: here is an example,

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{gauss}

\newcommand{\BAR}{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \strut\vrule % the `\vrule` is as high and deep as a strut
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
-1 & 0 & 1 &\BAR& 1 \ 1 & 1 &-2 &\BAR& 0 \ 0 & 1 & -1&\BAR& 0
 \rowops
 \add{0}{1}
  \mult{0}{\cdot -1}
\end{gmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}

Comment: Hi @egreg, it seems to be the align environment that's the problem...

Comment: @mhle Just yesterday I answered a question about `gmatrix` and `align`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146532/gauss-package-gmatrix-not-equivalent-to-corresponding-amsmath-environment Try the workaround there and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: @egreg I think the matrix must be \begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & \BAR & 3 \\    4 & 5 & \BAR & 6 \\    7 & 8 & \BAR & 9
\rowops
 \swap{0}{1}
 \mult{0}{\cdot 7}
 \add[5]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
Otherwise the code doesn't run. What I corrected is that the rows must be separated with \\, not \.

Comment: @Veliko For some reason, many lines of code have been modified by the site. I'll fix it

Comment: Nice workaround.  I wanted to make `\BAR` local to the `gmatrix` environment, so I tried to put the definition inside `\apptocmd{gmatrix}{\newcommand{\BAR}...}{}{}`.  Didn't work.  Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: Never mind, it seems `\pretocmd{gmatrix}{\newcommand{\BAR}...` works fine.