# Matrix with line and matrix operations

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to produce this matrix:

[image: example]

For the vertical line I can use `\begin{array}{cc|c}` and for the matrix operation I use environment `gmatrix` from the [`gauss`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gauss) package.
But I can't use these options at the same time.

Does anyone have a solution?

---

Update:

What I actually have:

```
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
    1 & 2 & \vline & 3 \\ 
    4 & 5 & \vline & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & \vline & 9
    \rowops
    \swap{0}{1}
    \mult{0}{\cdot 7}
    \add[5]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
```

and result:

[image: s]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe you got the image from my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/how-to-typeset-row-operations-on-augmented-matrix