# Vertical line in Gaussian reduction matrix

Tags: matrices

Try to represent Gaussian reduction in Latex but couldn't find way to correctly show the vertical line

```
\begin{pmatrix}[cc|c]
  1 & 2 & 3\\
  4 & 5 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
```

doesn't work

[image]

This works for me

```
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 1 & -1 \\  
 2 & 3 & 0  \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$
```

Comment: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/vertical-line-in-matrix-using-latexit) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because already solved by the OP himself!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/how-to-typeset-row-operations-on-augmented-matrix/146730#146730 may also be of interest. (And note that it is recommended to *not* use `$$ ... $$` for display math in LaTeX, use `\[ ... \]` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have this simpler code with `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}({@{}cc|c@{}})
     1 & 1 & -1 \\
     2 & 3 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]