# Augmented matrix with fractions

Tags: math-mode, matrices, fractions

I need to typeset some augmented matrices, but some of them contain fractions.
I also need to do that with `gmatrix`, as I need its features.

The following code is used to create the line in between the entries:

```
\newcommand{\mline}{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \strut\vrule
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}
```

With that I can create something like this:

[image: Example: Augmented matrix without fractions]

Code:

```
\begin{align} 
    \begin{gmatrix}[p] 
        1 & 2 & 3 & \mline & 40 \\
        2 & 3 & 4 & \mline & 500 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 & \mline & 6000
    \end{gmatrix} 
\end{align}
```

But when it contains fractions, it looks more like this:

[image: Example: Augmented matrix with fractions]

Code:

```
\begin{align} 
    \begin{gmatrix}[p] 
        1 & 2 & \frac{1}{3} & \mline & 40 \\
        2 & 3 & \frac{1}{4} & \mline & 500 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 & \mline & \frac{1}{6}
    \end{gmatrix} 
\end{align}
```

The line gets kind of dashed which does not really work. It also looks unaesthetic that the fractions almost touch.

I hope you are able to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you a manual fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

% patch gauss macros for doing their work in `align'
% and other amsmath environments; see
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146532/
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\g@matrix
 {\vbox\bgroup}
 {\vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines}% restore the standard baselineskip
 {}{}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\mline}[1][0pt]{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \ifdim#1>0pt
    \dimen0=\ht\strutbox \dimen2=\dimen0
    \advance\dimen0 #1\relax
    \ht\strutbox=\dimen0
  \fi
  \smash{\strut\vrule} % the `\vrule` is as high and deep as a strut
  % since assignments to \ht\strutbox are global, we restore the height
  \ifdim#1>0pt
    \ht\strutbox=\dimen2
  \fi
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & 2 & \mline & 3 \\
4 & 5 & \mline & 6 \\
7 & 8 & \mline[2pt] & \frac{1}{6}
\rowops
 \swap{0}{1}
 \mult{0}{\cdot 7}
 \add[5]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For conflicting fractions, use a new `\gfrac` macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

% patch gauss macros for doing their work in `align'
% and other amsmath environments; see
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146532/
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\g@matrix
 {\vbox\bgroup}
 {\vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines}% restore the standard baselineskip
 {}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\gfrac}[2]{\frac{\smash[b]{\mathstrut}#1}{\smash[t]{\mathstrut}#2}}

\newcommand{\BAR}[1][0pt]{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \ifdim#1>0pt
    \dimen0=\ht\strutbox \dimen2=\dimen0
    \advance\dimen0 #1\relax
    \ht\strutbox=\dimen0
  \fi
  \smash{\strut\vrule} % the `\vrule` is as high and deep as a strut
  % since assignments to \ht\strutbox are global, we restore the height
  \ifdim#1>0pt
    \ht\strutbox=\dimen2
  \fi
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
1 & \gfrac{1}{3} & \BAR & 3 \\
4 & \gfrac{1}{4} & \BAR[4pt] & 6 \\
7 & 8 & \BAR[2pt] & \frac{1}{6}
\rowops
 \swap{0}{1}
 \mult{0}{\cdot 7}
 \add[5]{1}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my advice is to use the slashed form for fractions.

Comment: @Kjadan Try the new version

Comment: `gfrac` will fix this problem. Slashed fractions would maybe solve it, but I really don't like the look of them. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, one thing: If a line of the matrix has no fraction it seems to be "thinner", which, of course, is logical. But do you know a small fix for that? So that all lines of the matrix are the same height?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} r r r | r @{}}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 40 \\
    2 & 3 & 4 & 500 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6000
  \end{array}\right)
  \qquad
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} r r r | r @{}}
    1 & 2 & \frac{1}{3} & 40 \\
    2 & 3 & \frac{1}{4} & 500 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & \frac{1}{6}
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Yes, you have to provide the column specification, but you have control over the alignment as well as using the default `|` column rule, which spans vertically without gaps.

Comment: I know that the problem would not exist if I use an array, but, as stated, I need the `rowops` `gmatrix` provides.