# Gaussian eliminations (gauss package)

Tags: matrices, gauss

I am trying to typeset some examples of Gaussian eliminations in LaTeX. I found the `gauss` package really simple to use, but couldn't figure out how to put a vertical line in between columns. Here is what I have so far (just a regular matrix)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gauss}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
$\begin{gmatrix}[p]
   2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \rowops
   \mult{0}{\cdot \frac{1}{2}}
\end{gmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: I would like it to be like this. Ignore the red color of the pen.]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: `Missing $ inserted.`. Could you extend your code fragment into a working document we can copy and paste please? It helps people help you and is a polite thing to do, I understand you are new so do not worry about not knowing

Comment: Maybe you will be interested in the following LaTeX package : [gaussenv](https://gitlab.com/AtticusSullivan/gaussenv)

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146730/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gauss}

% patch gauss macros for doing their work in `align'
% and other amsmath environments; see
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146532/
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\g@matrix
 {\vbox\bgroup}
 {\vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines}% restore the standard baselineskip
 {}{}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\BAR}{%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \strut\vrule % the `\vrule` is as high and deep as a strut
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gmatrix}[p]
2 & 9 & 1 & \BAR & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \BAR & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & \BAR & 0 & 0 & 1
\rowops
 \mult{0}{\cdot \frac{1}{2}}
\end{gmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `gauss` package does not provide for the use of vertical lines separating columns. I simply used a trick using `\bigl|` for 3 times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gauss}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\begin{gmatrix}[p]
   2 & 0 & 1  &\bigl| & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0  &\bigl| & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 3  &\bigl| & 0 & 0 & 1
   \rowops
   \mult{0}{\cdot \frac{1}{2}}
\end{gmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, may I suggest taking a look at the [nicematrix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) package? I used to work with `gauss` in the way [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681808/105539) has suggested above until I discovered nicematrix, and I have never looked back :-). It can do what you want and also offers a host of other options. Here is a suggested solution for your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
  $\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|ccc}[last-col]
    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot \frac{1}{2}\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{pNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where you use gauss package?

Comment: I don't, I'm using `nicematrix` instead to achieve the same goal.

Comment: The user want to use gauss package.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without to use `gauss` package but the simple functions of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 
   2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\begin{matrix} | \cdot \frac 12 \\ \\ \\ \end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]